# My modal automatically closes after clicking google places autosearch result

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I am having a google place autosearch functionality which works fine. But the input field is in a modal created with tailwind, So any time i click the autosearch result the modal closes and the input field is null, but when i use my keyboard to scroll and hit the enter key to select from the fetched results it works fine. And also without a modal everything works fine.

[image]

My Code

```
const apiKey = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_API_KEY;
const mapApiJs = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js';
const geocodeJson = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json';

// load google map api js

function loadAsyncScript(src: any) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    Object.assign(script, {
      type: "text/javascript",
      async: true,
      src
    })
    script.addEventListener("load", () => resolve(script));
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  })
}



const AddAddressForm: React.FC = () => {

  const searchInput = useRef(null);

   const initMapScript = () => {
    // if script already loaded
    if(window.google) {
      return Promise.resolve();
    }
    const src = `${mapApiJs}?key=${apiKey}&libraries=places&v=weekly`;
    return loadAsyncScript(src);
  }


   const onChangeAddress = (autocomplete: any) => {
    const place = autocomplete.getPlace();


  var lat = place.geometry.location.lat(),
      lng = place.geometry.location.lng();

  console.log(lat);
  console.log(lng);
  }

  // init autocomplete
  const initAutocomplete = () => {
    if (!searchInput.current) return;

    var options = {
      // bounds: defaultBounds,
      types: ['geocode'],
      componentRestrictions: {country: "us"}
     };

    const autocomplete = new window.google.maps.places.Autocomplete(searchInput.current, options);
    autocomplete.setFields(["address_component", "geometry"]);
    autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => onChangeAddress(autocomplete));
       
  }

 // load map script after mounted
 useEffect(() => {
  initMapScript().then(() => initAutocomplete())
}, []);





  return (
    <div className="w-full md:w-[600px] lg:w-[900px] xl:w-[1000px] mx-auto p-5 sm:p-8 bg-skin-fill rounded-md">
      <CloseButton onClick={closeModal} />
      <Heading variant="title" className="mb-8 -mt-1.5">
        {t('common:text-add-delivery-address')}
      </Heading>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} noValidate>
        <div className="grid grid-cols-1 mb-6 gap-7">  
          <Input
            label="Address"
            className="text-skin-base"
            variant="solid"
            ref={searchInput}
            placeholder={'Enter Delivery Address'}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="flex w-full justify-end">
          <Button className="h-11 md:h-12 mt-1.5" type="submit">
            Save Address
          </Button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddAddressForm;
```